# IIS 6.0 Memory allocation

Tags: iis, iis-6, memory

I need to find out how much memory does my .net application occupies in IIS 6.0. Can anyone tell me the steps to find out how much memory does my applicaion occupy in 6.0.

thanks in advance.

With regards,
ram

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your application into its own app pool, check Task Manager to see the memory consumption for that app pool.  Type iisapp from the command line to get a mapping of app pools to PIDs.